# WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread

Tags: java, scope, apache-tomee, openwebbeans

I'm using OpenJPA at TomEE server.

I build my .war, deploy it on server but i get this execption when i open page with my application:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
  javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)
  filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:42)
  org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
  com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)


javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
  org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:351)
  org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.getContextualCreationalContext(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:169)
  org.apache.webbeans.web.intercept.RequestScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.getContextualInstance(RequestScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:79)
  org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:114)
  org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:108)
  org.apache.webbeans.conversation.ConversationImpl_$$_javassist_0.isTransient(ConversationImpl_$$_javassist_0.java)
  org.apache.webbeans.jsf.WebBeansPhaseListener.beforePhase(WebBeansPhaseListener.java:106)
  org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersBefore(PhaseListenerManager.java:77)
  org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:158)
  org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
  javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
  filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:42)
  org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
  com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find where is problem.

First of all, I had to read log of starting my TomEE server. I found there, that I have problem with one of my EJB class. I inject there resource with transaction manager:

```
   @Resource
   private UserTransaction userTransaction;
```

but I forgot to anotate my service EJB by:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TaskService {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might also happen if "someone" uncritically deletes the login page for the application.